# Using an ACF gallery with Timber/Twig

Tags: twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

I'm using Timber (the WordPress plugin implementation of Twig) and the Advanced Custom Fields plugin gallery field. I have a working gallery under a custom post type, so ACF and Timber are working elswhere in the site, but not for a standard page. When I try to add a gallery to a page, all I end up with is empty markup for the `img src` tag.

I have this in page.php in the template folder:

```
$context = Timber::get_context();
$page = new TimberPost();

$context['page'] = $page;

if ($photos = $page->get_field('photos')) {
    $context['photos'] = $photos;
}
```

I have this in default.twig in the templates/page/ folder in the theme (html removed for simplicity):

```
{% if page.photos %}

{% for p in page.photos %}

<img src="{{ p.sizes.gallery|relative }}" alt="{{ p.alt }}" /> 

{{ p.caption }}

{% endfor %} 

{% endif %}
```

This results in the page source `<img src="" alt="">`.

If I use `{{ dump(photos) }}` inside the `for p in page.photos` statement, it dumps the array of images I have entered in the Gallery field on the backend. So the image array exists and it being output. The `relative` extension runs for all post types; removing it makes no difference here.

So why is the `p.sizes.gallery|relative` function not outputting each image's url and caption?

Comment: You append the data to the `$context['photos']` so shouldn't your code check for `if photos` and iterate as ` for p in photos` ?

Comment: @Owi, ah, that's it. Thanks. I just didn't see it. Add that as an answer.

Comment: I just added the answer, thanks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You append the data to the $context['photos'] so I believe you should change your code to check for `if photos` and iterate as `for p in photos`

Answer (score 0):

I have tested everything is working fine. Only thing which is incorrect is how the images are fetching in image tag. That's the reason for empty source and alt tag `<img src="" alt="">`.

Image tag supposed to be like this:

```
<img src="{{ Image(p).src }}" alt="{{ Image(p).alt }}"/>
```

For more information use Timber official website for [image](https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/cookbook-images/) related syntax. For Advanced custom field gallery syntax use this reference: https://timber.github.io/docs/guides/acf-cookbook/#gallery-field